# Building App for Windows CE 5.2 with Xamarin?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, xamarin, windows-ce

I have a Win-Forms Project in C#, written in VS2015 with separated GUI and Businesslogik.
One Part of this Programm I must "convert" to the App, which schould run on the handheld with Windows CE 5.2.

What is the best way to do it?
Is it possible to use Xamarin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows CE supports [.Net Compact Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286583.aspx), which is not in active development anymore. According to a post in the Xamarin forums, Xamarin doesn't support Windows CE or Windows Mobile 6.5: [Link to Xamarin forums discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14475/windows-ce-and-windows-mobile-6-5-support). If you have your BL layer separated, you could create a Compact Framework library re-using your source code. You'd still need a dedicated Compact Framework application for the devices. Support for these project types was removed from Visual Studio with Version 2010, so you need VS 2008 to develop for Windows CE.

Comment: Can I create a CompactFramework library in VS2015? Or ist it only possible with VS2008? Thank you!

Comment: VS 2015 doesn't support CompactFramework. So building the library wouldn't work, intellisense would likely not work because VS can't use the referenced libraries. It probably won't even open an existing CF project. And you can't create new CF projects with VS 2015.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to open my Project in vs2008 and build a library with BL .-(. Thank you!

Comment: It depends on the Windows CE release you are targeting.
If you target up to Windows CE 7 and .NET CF 3.5 you have to use VS2008, if you target Windows Embedded Compact 2013 and .NET CF 2013 you may use Visual Studio 2012, 2013 or 2015.